# Who am I?- I lived towards the end of the age of enlightenment

Tags: history

I was able show the deconstruction of the intellectual pretension of the Enlightenment. Everyone was under the assumption that reason and science are the only routes to reality and truth. I perceived the idea that we must go deeper into the mind and how it constructs the universe. Most of the Enlightenment had already written and debated their philosophies by the time I was born. I would help label this period.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling :) Are you sure that this is a puzzle and not just trivia? The answer could be Buddha, you know!

Comment: I'm talking about the age of enlightenment in Europe during the late 17th and 18th centuries. its might be both but you guys should still answer it(:

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you are almost certainly

> Immanuel Kant

but I am inclined to agree with ABcDexter that this is more trivia question than puzzle; one bit of evidence for that is that there really isn't much to say about *why* that's the answer beyond "Well, the description there does somewhat resemble what he did". Though I will mention, in connection with the last sentence, that

> the German word *Aufklärung* generally used for the period is found in the title of one of his works, which may be partially responsible for its use.

I'm not going to close it myself, not least because there isn't any very clear PSE policy on this sort of question; readers wondering whether or not to vote for closure may wish to have a look at [this Meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5160/what-should-we-do-about-riddles-that-are-pure-trivia) where the matter is discussed; there are two answers, both with quite positive scores, advocating different approaches.